# Notation for the Heisenberg group

Tags: group-theory, notation

I have the (matrix representation of the) Heisenberg group modulo 3.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}: a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$$

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) Wikipedia article, it is denoted $H$ generally, although that could be for any Heisenberg group. It seems to suggest $H_3(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ or even just $H_3$, (although I might be misreading this). $H_3$ is also used for a Coxeter group according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group).

[This reference](https://e-l.unifi.it/pluginfile.php/186951/mod_forum/attachment/27575/groupsp3.pdf) uses $\text{Heis}(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$.

Is there a standard peice of notation I should use, or something that'd generally be unambiguous in meaning?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) denotes the general Heisenberg group over a field $K$ by $H_{2n+1}(K)$, which is also the standard notation for its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}_{2n+1}(K)$. However, also the group of upper-triangular matrices of size $3$, $U_3(K)$, coincides with $H_3(K)$. So the answer is, there is no unique notation for the Heisenberg group. Probably Conrad's notation is best, since $H_3$ also denotes the third homology.